# Site returns 403

Tags: 9

This is a head-scratcher. I built a new Drupal 9 site on a RHEL test server with a temporary domain. Everything worked great. I moved it to the production server, again using a temporary domain, and everything worked great. This morning I set up the new Apache conf file on production. The site works fine as portal.yln.info and [www.yln.info](http://www.yln.info), but yln.info throws a 403 error (those three domains were working fine on the old Drupal 7 site). There are no errors in the Apache log.

Here's what I have in the conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info
        Redirect "/" "https://yln.info/"
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                #Include /var/www/drupal_2020/htaccess.conf
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/yln.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is yln.info inaccessible? I don't know if this is an Apache problem or a Drupal problem. I web searched but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Is `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` configured in `settings.php`?

Comment: Isn't it `require all granted` rather than `allow from all` these days?

Comment: @cilefen, I verified that my trusted_host_patterns settings are correct.

Comment: @Clive, good point. I've updated the conf file and will test it out tomorrow morning (business hours have begun so I can't experiment).

Comment: @Clive, I got authorization from above to go ahead and make the change to "require all". I'm still having the same problem where yln.info returns a 403.